# How to solve discrete time first order difference equations when b is a function of t?

Tags: recurrence-relations, economics

I am having some trouble solving this particular equation:
$y_{t+1}-2y_t=2^t$

Which brought me to realize that I don't even understand how to solve the general case of a difference equation $y_{t+1}-ay_t=b(t)$, where b is some function of t itself. So far my math course has only covered the cases where b is either a constant or equal to zero. I have tried to look online as to what the process for this is, but have only encountered videos/documents covering the two afformentioned cases. I would greatly appreciate some assistance or guidance as to what the process for solving such an equation is.

I am given no initial conidtions, however when I asked my professor he told me to use the stationary solution of the form $at2^t$, but I'm not quite sure what he means by this.

My apologies in advance if this is a stupid question, or if there are any formating errors present.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the recurrence

$$
y(k+1)-2y(k) = 2^k
$$

due to linearity, the solution $y(k)$ can be represented as $y(k) = y_h(k)+y_p(k)$ where

$$
\cases{
y_h(k+1) - 2y_h(k) = 0\\
y_p(k+1) - 2y_p(k) = 2^k
}
$$

The solution for $y_h(k)$ is $y_h(k) = 2^kc_0$. Now proposing $y_p(k) = 2^kc_0(k)$ after substitution we get

$$
2^{k+1}c_0(k+1)-2\cdot 2^kc_0(k) = 2^k
$$

and we have now the recurrence

$$
c_0(k+1)-c_0(k) = \frac 12
$$

with particular solution $c_0(k) = \frac k2$ and finally

$$
y(k) = 2^kc_0 + 2^k \frac k2
$$